# Unable to importfiles and parse files from s3 bucket to h2o flow version 3.22.0.2

Tags: amazon-s3, h2o

I used to pass the following format of file path to import datafiles from s3 buckets to H2O flow (version 3.18.0.10):

```
importFiles ["s3a://ACCESS KEY:SECRET KEY@parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/"]
```

After updating to version **3.22.0.2**, i get following error with the same file path.

```
Error calling GET /3/ImportFiles?path=s3a%3A%2F%2ACCESS KEY%3SECRET KEY%40parvin-us-west1-data%2FProd%2F154351418084_train%2F
--------------------
HTTP connection failure: status=error, code=500, error=Server Error
--------------------
```

It seems that now it expects different s3 filepath format, is there any documentation about how to pass s3 filepaths with credentials to latest version of h2o?

## Update:

After changing the configuration, i'm able to importfiles. After running the importfile cell, the following shows up.

### 1 / 1 files imported.

### Files   s3a://parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/data.csv

However when i press "parse these files", it shows new cell with the following content but does not make any progress:

### setupParse source_frames: [ "s3a://parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/data.csv"]

Also at the bottom of the page it says "Requesting /3/ParseSetup", but nothing happens. Even it does not give timeout error after 20 minutes.

The last line of terminal log is:
1283   #71051-12 INFO: POST /3/ParseSetup, parms: {source_frames=["s3a://parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/data.csv"]}

***Note about version (3.18.0.10) without this problem:***

after pressing the "parse these files":
It prompts the following information into a cell:

setupParse source_frames: ["s3a://ACCESS KEY:SECRET KEY@parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/data.csv"]

The difference is that it also includes credential part of url.

**Update:**

I also have tried to start h2o in standalone mode (using core-site.xml to pass credentials). 
Even in this case, it is not capable of parse the files, after importing them.

Comment: can you test accessing the following publicly available file and let me know if you still have an issue? so after you click `Import Files` paste in  `http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv` and see if that works. Please also specify how you started h2o: did you use h2o.init() - with what arguments. or did you start some other way. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it works with provided public file path. It seems that current version does not accept s3a protocol. How can i pass private file paths from s3 in this version? I'm using h2o.jar to start and run h2o flow

Comment: would it be possible for you to download and send your logs to support@h2o.ai? thanks!

Comment: @Lauren, Do you want a special subject or tag for the email to make it visible? (I will include the link of this thread as well.)

Comment: no special tag we will recognize the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Lauren. I just sent the email

Answer (score 1):

The file format should be the same (see option 3 at bottom of post), I did a quick test and it worked for me using `importFiles [ "s3a://<AWS_ACCESS_KEY>:<AWS_SECRET_KEY>@bucket/path/to/file.csv" ]`.

I would check if your connection is good, your cluster status, and if you can access the file any other way.

Here is what the current docs have for [H2O running in standalone mode](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cloud-integration/ec2-and-s3.html#aws-standalone-instance) you can also go to this link to see multi-node mode:

When running H2O in standalone mode using the simple Java launch command, we can pass in the S3 credentials in two ways.

You can pass in credentials in standalone mode by creating a core-site.xml file and pass it in with the flag -hdfs_config. For an example core-site.xml file, refer to Core-site.xml.

1. Edit the properties in the core-site.xml file to include your Access Key ID and Access Key as shown in the following example:

`<property>
      <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
      <value>[AWS SECRET KEY]</value>
</property>`

`<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>[AWS SECRET ACCESS KEY]</value>
</property>`

2. Launch with the configuration file core-site.xml by entering the following in the command line:
   `java -jar h2o.jar -hdfs_config core-site.xml`
3. Import the data using `importFile` with the S3 URL path: `s3://bucket/path/to/file.csv`. You can pass the Minio Access Key and Secret Access Key in an S3 URL in Flow, R, or Python (where AWS_ACCESS_KEY represents your user name, and AWS_SECRET_KEY represents your password).

To import the data from the Flow API:
`importFiles [ "s3://<AWS_ACCESS_KEY>:<AWS_SECRET_KEY>@bucket/path/to/file.csv" ]`

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I fixed the problem with importfile on 3.22.0.2 version.   Now by passing : importFiles ["s3a://ACCESS KEY:SECRET KEY@parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/"] it can import the file. However it cannot parse the file after that. Can you please confirm that you are also able to parse the file with this format of filepath? The issue is that when i press (parse these files) in 3.22 flow, the  source_frames, does not include the credential part of the url. While in  3.18 the source file of setupParse was also including the credentials.

Comment: @ParvinDadgar yes I was able to parse the file. Could you update your questions so that include the error message you are seeing? That might help see where our steps may have differed. thanks!

Comment: Sure. After pressing, parse these files, i get the cell with following content: setupParse source_frames: [ "s3a://parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/data.csv" ]. on the bottom of the page it says: Requesting /3/ParseSetup. It remained in this phase for 20 minutes. and in the logs it does not show anything after POST /3/ParseSetup, parms: {source_frames=["s3a://parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/data.csv" ].   In 3.18 version i used to get: setupParse source_frames: [ "s3a://ACCESS KEY:SECRET KEY@parvin-us-west1-data/Prod/154351418084_train/data.csv" ] which worked well.